# Sort dict and save as dict

Tags: python, sorting

So i have dictionary like this

```
   mydic={
    'a':3,
    'b':1,
    'c':2,}
    def sortedby():
        sort= (sorted(mydic.items(), key = lambda t : t[0]))


        return(sort)
    print(sortedby())
```

I would like to get it returned not as list or int but as dictionary

Comment: Uh... what would be the point of sorting it and then putting it back into the same arbitrarily-ordered container?

Comment: A dict is not sortable

Comment: Dictionaries are *unordered*. Are you looking for the `OrderedDict` type instead perhaps?

Comment: i get inputdata that i need to  sort from highest but i dont need value of it but index,key.

Comment: `from collections import OrderedDict

ordered_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))`

Answer (score 2):

Python's `dict` are not ordered. In order to maintain the order in the `dict`, you should use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

mydic = {
    'a':3,
    'b':1,
    'c':2,}
ordered_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(mydic.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))
# Store dict as: OrderedDict([('a', 3), ('b', 1), ('c', 2)])
#                 Sorted        ^         ^         ^
```